# mysql match against order by relevance

Tags: mysql, sql, match

i tried to order my result based on relevance and some sequence

```
SELECT d.s_title, oc_t_item.*, oc_t_item.s_contact_name as s_user_name,
  MATCH (d.s_title) AGAINST ('"myvi xt"') AS exact_phrase,
  MATCH (d.s_title) AGAINST ('+myvi +xt"') AS both_keyword
FROM (oc_t_item) LEFT JOIN oc_t_item_description as d
  ON d.fk_i_item_id = oc_t_item.pk_i_id
WHERE MATCH(d.s_title) AGAINST('myvi xt' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY exact_phrase desc, both_keyword desc LIMIT 1000
```

above query will return below result

[image]

so the problem is the result should be order by exact phrase first, example "**Myvi XT**" and then follow by "**Myvi some text XT**" but i already used `ORDER BY exact_phrase desc, both_keyword desc`

Comment: `mysql` sorted it by columns you asked. What is the problem?

Comment: Can you trying giving a common alias to both the Match ?

Comment: @zerkms the result should be `Perodua Myvi XT Manual 1.3`, `Perodua Myvi XT Auto 1.3` then follow by `Perodua MyVi 1.3 XT` order by should start with `myvi xt` first

Answer (score 1):

By default, the minimum word length for full text searches in MySQL is 4 letters.  That means that anything shorter is ignored.  Here is the relevant [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len):

```
ft_min_word_len

Command-Line Format --ft_min_word_len=#
Option-File Format  ft_min_word_len
System Variable Name    ft_min_word_len
Variable Scope  Global
Dynamic Variable    No
    Permitted Values
Type    numeric
Default 4
Min Value   1
The minimum length of the word to be included in a MyISAM FULLTEXT index.

Note
FULLTEXT indexes on MyISAM tables must be rebuilt after changing this variable. Use REPAIR TABLE tbl_name QUICK.
```

In other words, unless you have changed this default, the word `'xt'` is being ignored entirely in the query.